# Rails: Tweaking attribute of single object served through jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I am making an API that serves week-calendars (Monday through Sunday) in JSON format. Right now each week-calendar has the attributes 'name' (string), 'start_date' (time object, referring to the Monday on which the calendar starts). I am trying to use the jbuilder gem that comes with Rails.

Problem:

```
1) Calendars GET users/user_id/calendars/calendar_id serves JSON with information about the calendar
 Failure/Error: expect_json({name: calendar.name, start_date: Date.new(2015, 3, 2).strftime('%Y%m%d')})

   expected: "20150302"
        got: "2015-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"

   (compared using ==)
 # ./spec/requests/calendars_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I want to tweak the format in which the start_date is outputted slightly because then it will be easier to deal with on the frontend. This I know how to do (Time.now.strformat(%y%m%d) or whatever) but I don't know how to do it in the context of jbuilder. This is what I have in my jbuilder file:

```
 json.extract! @calendar, :name, :start_date
```

I have tried a lot of syntax from the builder docs but they all seem to apply to cases where I'm serving an array of JSON. In this instance I'm trying to serve a JSON representation of a single model.

My first question on stackoverflow so I hope this is relatively clear. Check the expectation for an idea of what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBuilder does not require that you only use `extract!()`.  Your .jbuilder file can look like this:

```
json.name @calendar.name  
json.start_date @calendar.start_date.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```

That syntax specifies each name/value pair that you want in your json on a separate line.

> In this instance I'm trying to serve a JSON representation of a single
>   model.

The output from above is:

```
{"name":"hello","start_date":"2000-01-01"}
```

Note that the rails column type `:time` does not store the correct date information in the database table--rails uses a dummy date of `2000-01-01`.  After all, you said you only wanted to store a time!  Because you are also interested in the date, you will need to use a different column type.

**A test:**

spec/requests/calendars_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "json API" do

  describe "GET calendars/1.json" do
    let(:calendar) { FactoryGirl.create(:week_calendar) }  #Create a WeekCalendar in the test db, and assign it to the variable calendar.

    it "returns the correct json" do
      test_calendar = {
        name: calendar.name,
        start_date: calendar.start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
      }

      visit '/calendars/1.json'
      expect(page.body).to eq(test_calendar.to_json)
    end
  end


end
```

spec/factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :week_calendar do
    name          "test"
    start_date    DateTime.new(2015, 2, 26)
  end
end
```

Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "4.2.0"
end
```

app/controllers/calendars_controller:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @calendar = WeekCalendar.find(params[:calendar_id])
    respond_to :json
  end
end
```

db/migrations/20150228082528_create_week_calendars.rb:

```
class CreateWeekCalendars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :week_calendars do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.datetime :start_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get "calendars/(:calendar_id)", to: "calendars#show"
```

Comment: Definitely a stud answer.